# Regular expression for rotator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build an ad rotator for my website and i need some help with my regular expression.

I basically need to parse through the html to locate all occurences of the following text.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    hsoub_adplace = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
    hsoub_adplace_size = 'XXXxXXX';
//--></script>
```

The complexity here is that the capital Xs are non-static integers  that change from ad to ad while the little one simply delimits width and height.

I basically need to be able locate all occurrences the above text within the entire html doc using the static elements, or any other method deemed viable.

I have tried in to no avail using multiple variants of :

```
('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is'.....)
```

All ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have u considered simply assigning new values to those variables?

Comment: what do you need to capture?

Comment: so, u need a bunch of numeric characters that comes immediately after hsoub_adplace =    and hsoub_adplace_size =

Comment: Sorry this was not clear enough. No i need to capture the entire contents of the <script> tag (including the <script>  tags themselves) but only the ones that contain hsoub_adplace and hsoub_adplace_size. As my webpage contains other javascript elements i dont wish to capture.

Comment: @blackfriday856 Something along these lines? https://regex101.com/r/kV8iJ7/1

Comment: @JoshCrozier thats almost exactly what i'm looking for. The only issue is that this only located the first occurence, of the desired <script> tag, my ad script is located on multiple instances in the html, with different identifier integers following hsoub_adplace and hsoub_adplace_size values.

Comment: @JoshCrozier i updated the regex link https://regex101.com/r/kV8iJ7/2 hopefully this will give you a clearer idea of what i'am trying to achieve.

In the example i provided i'am looking to match both instances (or as many as their may be in practice) of the said <script> tags. Please disregard the <div> those are just to illustrate my point. thanks a ton!

Comment: @blackfriday856 Then add the `g` flag to match all occurrences - https://regex101.com/r/zD8tB7/1

Comment: Awesome!!! I cant thank you enough.... this was bending my mind backwards. How can i up vote your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This will match the whole block

```
(<script[^>]+><!--\s*hsoub_adplace\s*=\s*\d+\s*;\s*hsoub_adplace_size\s*=\s* '\d+x\d+';\s*//--></script>)
```

Here we literally qualify as much as possible given the known criteria. If we had other heuristics to follow we could make the expression more compact. An example of a helpful heuristic might be 'any script block that contains hsoub will have everything we want to capture'. Or 'there is only one hsoub block per page'

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you want or why, so this might not be correct. If you need to capture the value of `hsoub_adplace` then

```
hsoub_adplace = (\w*);
```

captures it and offers a way to change it with a replace. Similarly for the size.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH5cV1/1)

If you really want to capture the whole block and what you have provided is true, then

```
<script.*--\n\s+hsoub_adplace[\w\s\=;']+\n.*script\>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH5cV1/2)